# COLLATION in DB2 order by

Tags: db2, sql-order-by, collation, db2-400

I want to change the default sequence of sorting in DB2.

For the query

```
> select * from table order by column;
```

**RESULT**

```
column
---
AR Man_dum

AR_dum

ARMGM

ARUSER
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
column
---

AR_dum

AR Man_dum

ARMGM

ARUSER
```

How can I achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: What operating-system runs your Db2-database server?  Is it z/os or i-series , or linux/unix/windows?  For Db2-LUW the collating sequence for a database is determined at database-creation time and cannot be changed. You have to recreate the database. But there are different approaches depending on the operating-system that runs the Db2-server.

Comment: We are using i-series

Comment: With 'Db2 for i', the mechanism to select a sort-sequence and sort language depends on which interface you are using to submit the SQL(i.e. jdbc, odbc etc. ). Apart from the default, there are built-in collating sequences that you can choose on the connection-string, or you can make your own custom sort sequence.  Suggest you study the iSeries documentation or get training in this subject-matter.